# How to keep float value before rounding in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, floating-point, nsstring, rounding

I've got some `NSString` equal `@"1234567.89"`. I have to make `floatValue` from this string. When I called `[myString floatValue]` then this `float` is equal `1234567.875000`. How to keep before this? I want have floatValue equal `1234567.89000`.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a float can't represent a number that large with the precision you're looking for. Try using a double instead, and retrieve it using `[myString doubleValue]`. The small example program below demonstrates this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *myString = @"1234567.89";
        float floatVal = [myString floatValue];
        double doubleVal = [myString doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"String: %@ float: %f double: %f", myString, floatVal, doubleVal);
    }
}
```

> String: 1234567.89 float: 1234567.875000 double: 1234567.890000